# Выделение в сети подсетей

Tags: ip, коммутатор

как можно выделить в сети 172.14.0.0/22  подсети подходящие для адресации 800, 400, 200, 50 компьютеров соответственно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

172.14.0.0/22 может быть до 1022 хостов. 800+400 уже не влезет - только 800.

23 маска - 510 хостов: сеть можно разбить на две

172.14.0.0/23 и 172.14.2.0/23

В 172.14.2.0/23 будет жить 400 хостов.

254 хоста влезет под маску 24 172.14.0.0/23 можно разбить на 2 сети: 172.14.0.0/24 и 172.14.1.0/24. 172.14.0.0/22 можно разбить на 4 сети 24маской.

126 хостов влезет под маску /25

63 хоста влезет под маску /26 - сеть 172.14.0.0/26 подойдет для 50 хостов

Comment: забыл добавить слово соответственно ))

Comment: @GingerBread куда?) я случайно опубликовал черновик?) с телефона набираю))